# 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to put the values of the index column of a dataframe into a variable as a list with the code

```
years = df.index
```

but it returns the error

```
'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I have also tried using the name of the index column like `df.Dates` but I get the same error. The index column is in date format.

I have tried converting the dates into string using

```
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].astype(str)
```

but I get the error

```
"only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"
```

I would appreciate some help. I am new to pandas

You can get the data here:

```
startdate = '2022-01-01'
enddate = '2022-12-31'
stocks = pdr.DataReader('SPY','yahoo', startdate, enddate)[['Adj Close']]
bonds = pdr.DataReader('TLT','yahoo', startdate, enddate)[['Adj Close']]
oil = pdr.DataReader('USO','yahoo', startdate, enddate)[['Adj Close']]

df = pd.concat([stocks, bonds, oil], axis=1, join='inner')
df.columns = ['SPY','TLT','USO']
```

Comment: share your data, otherwise we're just guessing here

Comment: the variable `df` is not a dataframe but rather a `pd. DatetimeIndex`

Answer (score 0):

Post your entire flow of code. Based on your second block of code you should be able to call df.index.  You've reassigned the variable df to the original dataframe's index somewhere in your actual code which is why it says

```
'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'index'
```